# Image files that saved in the Document Library can't open in computer Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I saved the Image file in the Document Library in iOS device using Objective-C and it works in UI image.
In this case I want to upload the file somewhere (Like Dropbox) it uploads successfully but I can't open the file and the computer error says that "the image file (Image.jpg) can no be opened. It may be damaged".
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx4Jj.png)

The problem is not in the uploading process because when I go to the document library folder I can not open that file neither.
The code that I used to save photos:

```
NSString *filePath = [self filesystemPathForURL:localURL];
CDVPluginResult* result = nil;
CDVFileError errCode = INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR;
int bytesWritten = 0;

if (filePath) {
    NSOutputStream* fileStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:shouldAppend];
    if (fileStream) {
        NSUInteger len = [encData length];
        if (len == 0) {
            result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDouble:(double)len];
        } else {
            [fileStream open];

            bytesWritten = (int)[fileStream write:[encData bytes] maxLength:len];

            [fileStream close];
            if (bytesWritten > 0) {
                result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsInt:bytesWritten];
                // } else {
                // can probably get more detailed error info via [fileStream streamError]
                // errCode already set to INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR;
                // bytesWritten = 0; // may be set to -1 on error
            }
        }
    } // else fileStream not created return INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR
} else {
    // invalid filePath
    errCode = NOT_FOUND_ERR;
}
if (!result) {
    // was an error
    result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsInt:errCode];
}
return result;
```

I also try this code:

```
    NSString *filePath = [self filesystemPathForURL:localURL];
[encData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

encData is the NSData of the imagefile.

Comment: What is the value of localURL & filePath? What is the file extension?

Comment: @satheeshwaran localURL is the URL of the where i want to save file and the file path is the NSString Path to write. in this case file path is: /Users/pourya/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/899805CA-A22A-488E-BF51-1A90DDECDB4C/data/Containers/Data/Application/C36064BC-D457-4797-AA62-BD4314C102A2/Documents/photo_021A3ADF-B7C2-4D00-93E4-65C08CC79137.jpg

Comment: @pouryadelnavaz I think the problem maybe you make the extension `.jpg` while you use `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:encData];
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

to

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:encData];
NSData *pngData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image);
```

Because your extension is .jpg but you are trying to write the png representation of the image that you have.

Comment: Ok it saved but the size of the file is Zero KB!

Comment: You have modified the code please give me the latest code that you are using. Why are you using NSOutputStream now? I need the complete code from where you capture the image and there on.

Comment: The code that i used to save file is the code that is modified. This is a function that i used to save every file not just image. but in this case i have problem with images